# Does this three value logic have a name?

Tags: logic

If I have three values and these truth tables:

Or:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & A & \text{true} & \text{false} \\ \hline
A & A & A & A \\ \hline
\text{true} & A & \text{true} & \text{true} \\ \hline
\text{false} & A & \text{true} & \text{false} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & A & \text{true} & \text{false} \\ \hline
A & A & A & A \\ \hline
\text{true} & A & \text{true} & \text{false} \\ \hline
\text{false} & A & \text{false} & \text{false} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

does this have a name? The construction is such that when A enters into a logic operation, the result is A, otherwise normal logic applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Bochvar's internal three-valued logic (also known as Kleene's weak three-valued logic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic#Bochvar.27s_internal_three-valued_logic_.28also_known_as_Kleene.27s_weak_three-valued_logic.29)